# Is there a method to override RouteServiceProvider::HOME in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have recently started learning Laravel. I am overriding the `redirectTo()` method in the default LoginController in my Laravel app.

```php
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        return '/dashboard';
    }
}
```

It is working fine but if an **already authenticated user** tries to login again (the user has not logged out and tries to visit the '/login' route), the user is redirected to '/home' which obviously is the RouteServiceProvider::HOME constant. I can simply change the RouteServiceProvider::HOME constant but there must surely be a better option. Also, if the redirect depends on the role of the user then simply changing the constant won't do any good. So what is the proper way of overriding the RouteServiceProvider::HOME constant?

Answer (score 10):

It's not a method but a constant.
You can change it in `app\Providers\RouteServiceProviders.php`
You'll find this line:

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

Change it for whatever you'd like.
If you don't want to change it and only change it locally in the

```
protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;
```

line to

```
protected $redirectTo = '/whatever'
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel8 you can override following method in LoginController

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    return redirect('/dashboard');
}
```

and in app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    
    
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        
        return redirect('/dashboard');
        
        //return redirect(RouteServiceProvider::HOME);

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the redirectTo method if you need a dyamic property.

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectTo() : string
{
    return '/dashboard';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 8 you can modify App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthenticatedSessionController.
On the last line of function Store() you can replace the constant ::HOME to a function in the same controller returning a string, like this example bellow.

```
public function store(LoginRequest $request)
{
    $request->authenticate();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended(self::home($request));
}

public static function home(LoginRequest $request) : string {

    $user_type = UserType::find($request->user_type_id);
    
    if ($user_type->name == 'Admin') {
        return '/dashboard';
    }

    return '/home';

}
```

This example is using $request data but you could also use Session instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the RouteServiceProvider.php in the folder app/Providers

/**
* The path to your application's "home" route.
*
* Typically, users are redirected here after authentication.
*
* @var string
*/
public const HOME = '/dashboard';

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).